# Retrofit - рабочий поток попадает в главный

Tags: android, retrofit2

Кастомный Call:

```
public class SourceCall {

    private Call<Source> call;
    private ErrorListener errorListener;
    private Object tag;

    SourceCall(Call<Source> call) {
        this.call = call;
    }

    public SourceCall setTag(Object tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
        return this;
    }

    public SourceCall error(ErrorListener errorListener) {
        this.errorListener = errorListener;
        return this;
    }

    public void success(final SourceCallback callback) {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Source>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Source> call, Response<Source> response) {
                Source source = response.body();
                if (source == null) {
                    handleError(NETWORK);
                } else {
                    callback.onResponse(source);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Source> call, Throwable t) {
                handleError(NETWORK);
            }
        });
    }

    public void success(final SourceTagCallback callback) {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Source>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Source> call, Response<Source> response) {
                Source source = response.body();
                if (source == null) {
                    handleError(NETWORK);
                } else {
                    callback.onResponse(tag, source);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Source> call, Throwable t) {
                handleError(NETWORK);
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleError(int errorCode) {
        if (errorListener != null) {
            errorListener.onError(errorCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Конвертер:

```
class SourceCallAdapterFactory extends CallAdapter.Factory {

    @Override
    public CallAdapter<?, ?> get(final Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new CallAdapter<Source, SourceCall>() {
            @Override
            public Type responseType() {
                return returnType;
            }

            @Override
            public SourceCall adapt(Call<Source> call) {
                return new SourceCall(call);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Класс, использующий ретрофит:

```
public class LoginRequest {

    private String nick, password;

    public LoginRequest(String nick, String password) {
        this.nick = Character.toUpperCase(nick.charAt(0)) + nick.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void execute(final ActionRequestListener listener) {
        RetrofitClient.getApi().loginPage()
                .error(listener)
                .success(loginDoc -> {
                    HashMap<String, String> postData = FormParser.parse(loginDoc)
                            .findByAction("loginForm")
                            .input("login", nick)
                            .input("password", password)
                            .build();
                    RetrofitClient.getApi().login(loginDoc.wicket(), postData)
                            .error(listener)
                            .success(resultDoc -> {
                                Element profileLink = resultDoc.select("div.ftr>a:contains(Мой профиль)").first();
                                if (profileLink != null) {
                                    long userId = Utils.getValueAfterLastSlash(profileLink.attr("href"));
                                    SkyscrapersSDK.saveAuthData(nick, password, userId);
                                    listener.onSuccess();
                                } else if (resultDoc.hasFeedBack(Feedback.Type.ERROR, "Неверное имя или пароль")) {
                                    listener.onError(Error.WRONG_DATA);
                                } else {
                                    listener.onError(Error.UNSUPPORTED_SOCIAL_NETWORK);
                                }
                            });
                });
    }
}
```

Когда я вызываю метод `execute` этого класса из активности я не могу размещать код работающий с UI ни в `onSuccess` ни в `onError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявите в UI потоке хендлер:

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

И из колбеков ретрофита его вызывайте. К примеру:

```
public void execute(final ActionRequestListener listener) {
    RetrofitClient.getApi().loginPage()
            .error(listener)
            .success(loginDoc -> {
                HashMap<String, String> postData = FormParser.parse(loginDoc)
                        .findByAction("loginForm")
                        .input("login", nick)
                        .input("password", password)
                        .build();
                RetrofitClient.getApi().login(loginDoc.wicket(), postData)
                        .error(listener)
                        .success(resultDoc -> {
                            Element profileLink = resultDoc.select("div.ftr>a:contains(Мой профиль)").first();
                            if (profileLink != null) {
                                long userId = Utils.getValueAfterLastSlash(profileLink.attr("href"));
                                SkyscrapersSDK.saveAuthData(nick, password, userId);
                                listener.onSuccess();

                                mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // здесь можно работать с UI
                                    }
                                });

                            } else if (resultDoc.hasFeedBack(Feedback.Type.ERROR, "Неверное имя или пароль")) {
                                listener.onError(Error.WRONG_DATA);
                            } else {
                                listener.onError(Error.UNSUPPORTED_SOCIAL_NETWORK);
                            }
                        });
            });
}
```

Comment: неееее, это же все портит.. мне надо будет все хендлерами истыкать! все вызовы `onSuccess` и `onError`

Comment: @Flippy в голову другое решение пока не приходит.

Comment: может быть в классе `SourceCall` это делать?

Comment: я создал хендлер при инициализации сдк и заменил один вызов onError на вызов из-под хендлера а второй не трогал. Первый работает отлично, второй - нет. Не очень красиво, но работает. Наверное, надо как-то в сам интерфейс перенести вызов из под хендлера, чтобы везде писать `listener.onSuccess` как и раньше, а сам код хендлера внутри класса листенера

Comment: и все таки надо попробовать вызывать из `SourceCall`